# ImportError: No module named requests_oauthlib

Tags: python, oauth, raspberry-pi, twython

Trying to tweet on my Raspberry Pi. Installed both Twython and oauthlib without problem. But can't get past this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweet_test.py", line 3, in 
    from twython import Twython

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/**init**.py", line 23, in 
    from .api import Twython

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 14, in 
    from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1, OAuth2

ImportError: No module named requests_oauthlib

*Original*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from twython import Twython

tweetStr = "Tweet text!"

apiKey = 'apiKey'
apiSecret = 'apiSecret'
accessToken = 'A_token'
accessTokenSecret = 'A_token_secret'

api = Twython(apiKey,apiSecret,accessToken,accessTokenSecret)

api.update_status(status=tweetStr)

print "Tweeted: " + tweetStr
```

Comment: How did you install Twython but not requests_oauthlib? Did you not use `pip`?

Comment: I thought I did. Here's the sequence I followed:
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools, 
sudo easy_install pip, 
sudo pip install twython

Answer (score -1):

Try this it will work

sudo apt-get install -y python3-oauth python3-oauth2client python3-oauthlib python3-requests-oauthlib